# Weird probled with TFT LCD screen and DHT22 sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, lcd

I'm doing a research project that uses three sensors ([DHT22](https://www.adafruit.com/product/385), HTU21D and TMP102) and two screens (a normal 16x2 LCD, and a TFT).

I connected all the sensors and the LCD in my Arduino Uno and everything works fine. However, when I connect the TFT, the TFT simply freezes and does nothing. I ran the example Arduino sketches for TFT and it works fine. I also did a bit of debugging and found that if I don't invoke the [DHT22 sensor reading functions](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/DHT.h) (i.e., dht.readTemperature()), the TFT screen works fine.

I also triple-checked the wiring and it doesn't seems that something is wrong.

Any ideas why this behaviour occurs? Thanks.

Comment: sounds like you need to configure the DHT to use a different GPIO

Comment: Similar problem have someone else here too: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34987/ultrasonic-sensors-with-12v-motors-will-not-work-adruino - there was some shared pins, so each device worked separately, but not both togeher. Changing the pins (GPIO) solved that.

Comment: Thank you, both. The problem was shared pins between the components. Now, I must figure out how to extend the outputs pins on Arduino!

Comment: To get more pins on an Arduino, look at the MCP23008 port expander.